# How to tell dropzone.js the upload is complete?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying out dropzone.js and can't figure out how to let the browser know the upload is complete.

I am using [this example](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html) as my base. It sends it to the right action, I got it to send the csrf-token but I can't seem to find how to sent it progress data and tell it when the upload is done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
      // Now that the DOM is fully loaded, create the dropzone, and setup the
      // event listeners
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
      myDropzone.on("success", function(file) {
        /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
      });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really need to do anything with the file but that doesn't stop the progress bar

Comment: Check the documentation, i guess using totaluploadprogress or uploadprogress you can stop the progress bar. http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Comment: Thanks but the docs are almost completely worthless. I will find a better library